# image is not showing up in Django Template but found the image path

Tags: django, django-templates

I used custom dynamic path for Imagefield. My image has been uploaded perfectly in desired folder. But the image did not show up in my template.The template found the image path with //,but can not show up the image.How to solve it?

This is my settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/faisal/workspace/pandora/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
'/home/faisal/workspace/pandora/Static/' ,  
)
```

This is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
 url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
 url(r'^async/gallery/',include('gallery.urls')),  
 url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': '/home/faisal/workspace/pandora/media',}),
```

)

and this is my template tag

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ image.photo.url }}" alt="{{ image.title }}" />
```

and this is my views.py:

```
return render_to_response('gallery/image.html', 
{  
    'e_piclist' : e_piclist, 

},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In my template instead of showing image ,this showed image alt.

What wrong am I doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image tag need not have `{{MEDIA_ROOT}}`, update the tag as

```
<img src="{{ image.photo.url }}" alt="{{ image.title }}" />
```

The `image_field.url` provides absolute path. Refer point 3 at [File field storage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.storage)